# Can we fetch data from Kafka from specific offset in spark structured streaming batch mode

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

In kafka I get new topics dynamically and I have to process it using spark streaming from a specific offset. Is there a possibility to pass the json value from a variable. For example consider the below code

```
val df = spark
 .read
 .format("kafka")
 .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
 .option("subscribePattern", "topic.*")
 .option("startingOffsets", """{"topic1":{"0":23,"1":-2},"topic2":{"0":-2}}""")
 .load()
```

In this I want to dynamically update value for startingOffsets... I tried to pass the value in string and called it but it did not work... If I am giving the same value in startingOffsets it is working. How to use a variable in this scenario?

```
val start_offset= """{"topic1":{"0":23,"1":-2},"topic2":{"0":-2}}"""
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribePattern", "topic.*")
  .option("startingOffsets", start_offset)
  .load()
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected e.g. {"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1},"topicB":{"0":-2}}, got """{"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1},"topicB":{"0":-2}}"""
```

Comment: have you tried start_offset.stripMargin ?

Comment: why whats wrong with the code ? I have set similar values in my Spark job but not via code. @thebluephantom

Comment: I added batch to title

Comment: I was about to tell him that in my ans

Comment: Cool u r sir,...thinking a sir...

Comment: There seesm to be correction in question `"1":-2` is as input in your source code but the exception says `got ..."1":-1` how come ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("ReadSpecificOffsetFromKafka");
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("error");
    import spark.implicits._;

    val start_offset = """{"first_topic" : {"0" : 15, "1": -2, "2": 6}}"""
    val fromKafka = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092, localhost:9093")
      .option("subscribe", "first_topic")
//      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("startingOffsets", start_offset)
      .load();

    val selectedValues = fromKafka.selectExpr("cast(value as string)", "cast(partition as integer)");

    selectedValues.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode("append")
//      .trigger(Trigger.Continuous("3 seconds"))
      .start()
      .awaitTermination();
  }
```

This is the exact code to fetch specific offset from kafka using spark structured streaming and scala

Answer (score -1):

- Looks like your job is check pointing the Kafka offsets onto some
  persistent storage. Try cleaning those. and Re run your Job.
- Also try renaming your job and running it.

Spark can read the stream via `readStream`. So try with an offset displayed in the error message to get rid of the error.

```
spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
.option("subscribePattern", "topic.*")
```

Comment: I modified my code little bit. In place of "subscribe" I used "subscribePattern" to fetch data from all topics which matches that pattern. So as my topic list is dynamic, my startingOffsets should also be dynamic. For example, If I have  three topics with topic names as topic1,topic2 and topic3 then from ```.option("subscribePattern", "topic.*")``` I will get three partitions, but if I define ```val start_offset= """{"topic1":{"0":23,"1":-2},"topic2":{"0":-2}}"""``` then this issue occurs because I am not specifying the offset details of topic3. So, startOffsets should also be dynamic.

Comment: Good to hear @Raghu_Ram